# the point of the Field extension method

Tags: linq, datatable, field

What is the point of the **Field** extension method on DataRow (for untyped DataTables)?

Here is a comparison of using **Field** or not using it.

with **Field**:

```
myRow.Field<Guid>("myColName")
```

without **Field**:

```
(Guid)myRow["myColName"]
```

I don't see any compelling improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension methods abstract away the concept of `DBNull`, in both directions - `Field` and `SetField`, for reference types and nullable value types. For non-nullable value types they are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The extension method supports nullable types. For instance:

`myRow.Field<Guid?>("myColName")`