# "Specified cast is not valid" in LINQ when DateTime field is null

Tags: c#, exception, datetime

I got a problem. This my code use a LINQ.

```
var resultCases = from row2 in dtCases.AsEnumerable()
                  where row2.Field<int>("caseID") == caseID2
                  select new
                  {
                              caseName = row2["caseName"].ToString(),
                              caseCourtPlace = row2["caseCourtPlace"].ToString(),
                              caseCourtRef = row2["caseCourtRef"].ToString(),
                              caseOfficeRef = row2["caseOfficeRef"].ToString(),
                              effectiveDate = ((DateTime)row2["caseEffectiveDate"]),
                              closedDate = ((DateTime)row2["caseClosedDate"]),
                              caseFolderPath = row2["casesFolderPath"].ToString(),
                              category = row2["categoryName"].ToString(),
                              department = row2["departmentName"].ToString(),
                              empName = row2["empName"].ToString(),
                              judgeName = row2["judgeName"].ToString(),
                              asName = row2["asCasesName"].ToString(),
                  };
```

If `closedDate` or `effectiveDate` return `DBnull.Value`, I get

> *InvalidCastException was unhandled - Specified cast is not valid.*

So how can I prevent this error?

Comment: Does `row2["caseEffectiveDate"]` return `null` or `DBNull.Value`? They are different. In any case, `row.Field<DateTime?>("caseEffectiveGate")` is what I would start with ..

Comment: @pst..Sorry for misunderstanding.. Yes, it return DBNull.Value..

Comment: So then start with `row.Field<DateTime?>..` does it work? (It should return `null` for `DBNull.Value` and then can be used with the coalesce - `??` - operator if a nullable DateTime isn't allowed.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tldr; **The issue is two-fold: DataTable uses `DBNull.Value` to represent "null" values and neither `DBNull.Value` or `null` are castable to `DateTime`.**

The [`Field<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298042.aspx) extension method was added later to make dealing with DBNull and Nullable/reference types with null values much easier; it also hides the conversion behind a strongly-typed signature. These [LINQ to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx) extension method [knows how to map `DBNull.Value` to `null` as appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039761/the-point-of-the-field-extension-method).

Because of this using `row.Field<DateTime?>("caseEffectiveDate")` will return *either* the `DateTime?` with a value (if the query returned a value) or `null`, and it may also throw an exception if the server returned an incompatible value - but it will *never* return `DBNull.Value`.

However, the standard `row["caseEffectiveDate"]` will return a `DateTime` value (or some other type) or `DBValue.Null` which is *not* cast-able to `DateTime?` (much less a `DateTime`) and results in the error described.

Here is how to minimally reproduce this exception:

```
object v = DBNull.Value;
DateTime dt = (DateTime)v;
```

However, it is fine to convert a `null` to a `DateTime?`:

```
object v = null;
DateTime? maybeDt = (DateTime?)v;
```

And then trivial to coalesce it away to `DateTime` if required:

```
object v = null;
DateTime? dt = (DateTime?)v ?? DateTime.MinValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: try this

```
public static class ConversionExtensions
{
    public static string SafeDateTime(this object value)
    {
        if (value == DBNull.Value) return string.Empty;

        var valueType = value.GetType();
        if (typeof (DateTime?).IsAssignableFrom(valueType))
        {
            var nullableValue = value as DateTime?;
            if (nullableValue == null) return string.Empty;
            return nullableValue.Value.ToString();
        }
        if (typeof (DateTime).IsAssignableFrom(valueType))
        {
            return ((DateTime) value).ToString();
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Called with:

```
effectiveDate = row2["caseEffectiveDate"].SafeDateTime()
```

Comment: @armen.shimoon.. Got same problem, thanks for help. You have another suggestion?

Comment: Thanks mate, i just do row2.Field<DateTime?>("caseEffectiveDate").. And it`s work.. thanks for help..

Comment: @Chuki2 That seems much better actually, thanks for the update.